# Convert DataRowCollection to DataRow[]

Tags: c#, performance, datarow, datarowcollection

What's the best performing way to convert a DataRowCollection instance to a DataRow[]?

Answer (score 108):

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select();
```

Assuming you still have access to the datatable.

Comment: Simplest answer, and correct. Should be marked as the accepted answer. This question now has 3,500 views!

Answer (score 18):

For the sake of completeness, this is another way (with Linq), and it *preserve the row ordering*:

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray()
```

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of obvious, but:

`DataRowCollection.CopyTo(DataRow[] array, Int32 offset)` ?

It seems like no matter what, you're going to have to iterate the collection (CopyTo iterates the internal DataRowTree elements).

I suppose you could use reflection to access the non-public tree, but at a significant cost.

Answer (score 5):

If you have not access to the containing table, you may use the extension method:

```
public static class DataRowCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DataRow> AsEnumerable(this DataRowCollection source)
    {
        return source.Cast<DataRow>();
    }
}
```

And thereafter:

```
DataRow[] dataRows = dataRowCollection.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
```

But if you have access to the containing table, it's better to access rows using `DataTable`'s `AsEnumerable` extension method ([Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/a.html#234b3444d2a5ff75)):

```
DataRow[] dataRows = dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
```

Either way you may use `DataTable`'s `Select` method with several overloads ([Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx), [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/R/d57c1612e35a7f9a.html)):

```
DataRow[] dataRows = dataTable.Select();
```